# How to detect if inside ReactDOMServer or ReactDOM context

Tags: reactjs, dom

I want to detect if the current component is being rendered by ReactDOM or by ReactDOMServer. The classic canUseDom

```
const canUseDOM = () => Boolean(
  typeof window !== 'undefined'
  && window.document
  && window.document.createElement
)
```

won't work, because ReactDOMServer can also be used in a broswer context where window is defined. I want to do something like this:

```
const MyComponent = () =>
  isRenderedByReactDOM()
    ? (<div>I am being rendered by ReactDOM.render</div>)
    : (<div>I am being rendered by ReactDOMServer.renderToString / ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup</div>)
```

Answer (score 2):

Server side components don't execute `componentDidMount()`. That's where you should put any purely browser side logic.

Comment: Thanks, I eventually solved it by using a context, similar to the redux provider.